# Java request.getParameter

Tags: java, jsp

Confirm : We can pass in the Controller then output back to jsp , we will use 
model.addAttribute("abc", abc); ==> JAVA
request.getParameter("abc"))) ==> JSP

But I not sure how to use getParameter?

Sometime I can get request.getParameter("abc") value, sometime may not.

I already compare both : the working one with not working one.

Both have HttpSession session But the not work one still not working.

May I know what problem?

Thanks
-fsloke

Comment: it's absolutely unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

I'll hazard a guess at a solution, though I'm not convinced I understand your problem in its entirety.

Based on what you're saying, it seems like you're confused that sometimes `request.getParameter("abc")` returns a value, and sometimes it does not.  This method looks up the parameters from the incoming request - so it will return a value only if there was one specified on the query string (or POST data) of the incoming request.

It sounds like you might have thought that this looks up something from the session, based on your fifth paragraph.  But the existence of a *session* is **completely unrelated** to what parameters are available on an incoming *request*.  If you want to look up something from the session, you should call `session.getAttribute("abc")` instead.